# Do any Hollywood movies star only little people?

Tags: cinema-history, american-cinema

Has Hollywood ever produced movies starring **only** [little people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwarfism) (i.e. those with dwarfism) as actors?

Comment: Not completely midget, but a large percentage of the actors in [Under The Rainbow (1981)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083254/) were "little people".

Comment: Define "Starring". Like full cast, or just main/title roles? Willow for example, has 5 people starring, but only one is Warwick Davis, and a much larger full cast.

Comment: [Even Dwarfs Started Small](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0065436/)

Answer (score 8):

I haven't seen it to confirm that every single actor is a little person, but [The Terror of Tiny Town](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0030845/) is the film that comes immediately to mind.